# Azure: step by step to upload sql server db dump (small) to azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

hell, I am completely new to azure

would like to know step by step to create sql server in azure and import a local db dump to it. Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: went through few labs to get on to azure portal and create resource group, work with few properties such as create blob storage etc and publish a website. taking it to more real now. I have aken a subset of db dump and ready to store in cloud - was looking for a lab or step by step to be able to do it. Labs I searched online are a little bit advance,  looking for a beginner lab to setup SQL server in azure and import db dump

Comment: I have azure basic pass from www.microsoftazurepass.com. Can someone please guide step by step (1) setting up sql server and creating a db in azure (2) import .bak to azure sql server db

Answer (score -1):

You could follow [Create an Azure SQL database in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal) to set up azure sql server and create a sql database on azure.

A BACPAC file can be imported to Azure and can be used as a standard SQL database in Cloud.

**Import using the Azure portal only supports importing a BACPAC file**.

You could create a  BACPAC file first and import the file into Azure, refer to this [article](https://developersource.wordpress.com/2017/05/04/import-bak-file-to-azure-sql-database/).

Here is [Import a BACPAC file to a new Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import) using azure portal or SQLPackage or powershell.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an Azure SQL Database using Azure Portal as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal), then you can use [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) to move your localdb database to your newly created Azure SQL Database server.